# Query retrieval of hibernate uuid

Tags: java, hibernate, uuid

I am having an issue of retrieving a value that is uuid. This is the query that I am using:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM expenses e WHERE username LIKE :user_name AND (e.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE())").setParameter("user_name", user.getUsername());
```

If I type this into the command line using MySQL I get back the desired results.

```
SELECT * FROM expenses WHERE username LIKE '531570ca-e802-44e6-b4fc-87c5dc7531d9';
```

This is what I have set for the field username

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
private String username;
```

Comment: how did you encode the uid ?    use new String(Base64.encode(user->getUsername()), 
        Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));

Comment: "I am having an issue" - which issue? What exactly doesnt behave like expected?

Comment: @f1sh Retrieving the desired username is the issue. If I use the UUID that is generated instead of the parameter it works fine.

Comment: @CodeIsLife I didn't encode it, I might have misled you when I said uuid encoded. That was due to lack of knowledge and I just edited my post after some research.

Comment: @CharlesSexton what do you mean by "retrieve the username"? The username is a parameter, so you don't retrieve it but pass it as a value. And the usernames are generated by hibernate so you need to pass a uuid as a parameter...

Comment: @f1sh how do i dynamically pass a hibernate generated uuid? username is a column in the expense table. If I want to use a where clause to see if a username is like a specific name how would I do that when the username column is a hibernate generated uuid? Hopefully this helps with my lack of knowledge and poor choice of words.

Comment: Is the question still unclear?